# Star raty plugin not set value after error on page in php

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am using [star ratty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) in code igniter. I want to check the checked star when it comes from controller because of some error. Apart from that it work fine.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#click').raty({
        scoreName : 'score',
        number    : 7,
        click: function(score){
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Please Give a hint how to procceed .Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what is that `some error` and what do you mean by `I want to check the checked star when it comes from controller` I can't understand your question here?

Comment: It simple means that I saved its Numeric value  in db as 1 or 2 . And I want to highlight the star according to that value .